# Do players get points for matches in Davis Cup and Fed Cup in ATP/WTA rankings

Tags: tennis, ranking, atp, wta, davis-cup

Do players, who represent their countries in Davis Cup/Fed Cup, receive also some points in ATP rankings/WTA rankings?

If yes, is it for matches on any level? Or only matches in World Group?

Are the points from team competitions counted in both rankings - race ranking and ATP/WTA ranking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is - *it depends*. ATP players started receiving points under certain conditions in 2009. See the rules for Davis Cup results and ATP rankings [here](http://www.atpworldtour.com/Rankings/Rankings-FAQ.aspx#daviscup) ([Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20140425201253/http://www.atpworldtour.com/Rankings/Rankings-FAQ.aspx#daviscup)):

> Davis Cup points are awarded for World Group and World Group playoff
>   ties only. The points accumulated in the four ties within the previous
>   52 weeks can be used as one of the player’s best of six (6) results.
>   If a particular Davis Cup round shows up twice within the 52-week
>   window, the best one of those two results will count towards the
>   player’s Davis Cup result. (This will come into play when a tie is
>   played earlier in the year compared to the previous year and both ties
>   fall within the 52-week window.)

The Fed Cup system works differently from Davis Cup and WTA players are not awarded any points for participation in Fed Cup ties. This probably has some to do with the fact that Fed Cup is governed by a different organization (ITF) than the pro womens tour (WTA) is.

Comment: Someone mentioned to me in an internet discussion, that WTA was considering doing something similar. Do you happen to remember, whether that is a case? (Whether they were seriously discussing about doing this?

Comment: Yes, I've heard that it's something the WTA players would like to be rewarded with for playing Fed Cup. I think the only thing holding it up is the WTA and ITF getting together and agreeing to the terms of how points would be awarded - similar to what the ATP did with the ITF years ago to figure out what the rules would be for the men.

Comment: Maybe it is also worth mentioning that points are not awarded for dead rubbers. At least that is what I read on Davis Cup website: http://www.daviscup.com/en/rankings/atp-ranking-points.aspx

Comment: Something you learned recently while watching Great Britain take on Belgium Martin? ;) haha

Comment: Davis Cup is also governed by ITF.

Comment: I think from 2016 onwards no longer Davis cup ties are counted towards ATP points. I haven't verified.

Answer (score 4):

As of 2016, no. The Davis Cup used to for world group matches, but not any more.

From the [ATP world tour website → Rankings FAQ](https://www.atpworldtour.com/en/rankings/rankings-faq):

> **What are the rankings rules for players who compete in Davis Cup?**
>
> Beginning in 2016 no points have been awarded for Davis Cup ties.