# What will be the Davis Cup format from 2019?

Tags: tennis, davis-cup, championship

Currently, the Davis Cup consists in a series of heats throughout the year (on February, March, May and November, if I recall properly), each one where the winner needs to get three matches to make it to the next round. The location of the matches is the country of one of the countries in the heat.

However, on August 16, 2018, the International Tennis Federation approved a modification of the format of the Davis Cup. Instead of what I described above, there seem to be a kind of Final Four, consisting on a week of matches in a Round-robin system, to get into a final.

In [A new era for international tennis as Davis Cup gets extreme makeover](https://www.thestar.com/sports/tennis/2018/08/16/international-tennis-federation-approves-new-format-for-davis-cup.html) I see some descriptions about the system:

> 24 nations will compete in a home-or-away qualifying round in February, with the 12 winners advancing to the final tournament. They will be joined by the four semifinalists from the previous year, along with two wild-card teams, who need to be in either the top 50 of the Davis Cup rankings or have a top-10 singles player to be eligible.
>
> The finalists will be placed into six, three-team groups for round-robin play, involving two singles matches and one doubles, all best-of-three-sets — instead of the current best-of-five format featuring four singles matches and one doubles. The winners, along with the next two teams with the best records, will advance to the single-elimination quarterfinals.

Still, I have some questions about it:

- How will those 24 countries selected?
- What will the format be exactly?
- Will the results count towards the ATP ranking? ([Since they 2016 do not](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/15879/11439))
- How will the hosting country be elected?
- Are there plans to extend this into the Fed Cup for women?